# Why the Image Asset tool in Android Studio, doesn't generate PNG file for xxxhdpi folder?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 3.6

I was wondering, why the Image Asset tool in Android Studio, doesn't generate PNG file for xxxhdpi folder?

[image]

With such limitation, I always have to look for icons from 3rd party website (For instance, https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) which provides xxxhdpi icon.

Comment: Android will automatically resample the `xxhdpi` icon to scale it for `xxxhdpi` screens as needed. Similarly, the Image Asset Wizard does not create `tvdpi` or `ldpi` images. My guess is that they focus on the image densities for which there is the most value, as many apps will have their icons working fine with the scaled results.

Comment: But, isn't upscale xxhdpi icon to display on xxxhdpi device, will end up with a blurry icon?

Comment: That will depend a lot on the icon and whatever image scaling algorithm that the particular version of Android uses (and perhaps tweaks by the device manufacturer). And, you are assuming that the on-device image scaling is dramatically worse than what Android Studio itself does with this wizard, which itself is scaling the supplied bitmap. Implicitly, Google is saying "if you are using this tool, you probably don't care about `xxxhdpi`". Similarly, implicitly, Google is saying "if you care about `xxxhdpi`, use Photoshop and a graphic designer, not the Image Asset Wizard".

Comment: I have the same question. It also seems like in older versions of Android Studio, the png for xxxhdpi would be created. I'd like to know why this has been changed.